# What does it mean if country X has a higher GDP at Purchasing Power Parity (PPP) than country Y?

Tags: macroeconomics, purchasing-power-partity

I understand the implications of having a higher/lower GDP at market exchange rates. I also understand what PPP measures.

But, what does a difference in GDP, at PPP, indicate in terms of differences in *levels*?

Answer (score 1):

I like this explanation from [Callen (2007)](http://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/fandd/2007/03/basics.htm), published in the IMF's F&D, their quarterly magazine.  For measuring consumption in a country, PPP is probably the way to go, but international economic and financial power is probably better measured with market rates.

> **PPP versus market rates**
>
> So which method is better? The appropriate way to aggregate economic
> data across countries depends on the issue being considered. Market
> exchange rates are the logical choice when financial flows are
> involved. For example, the current account balance represents a flow
> of financial resources across countries. It is appropriate to use the
> market exchange rate to convert these flows into dollars when
> aggregating across regions or calculating the global current account
> discrepancy. But for other variables, the decision is less clear cut.
> Take real GDP growth. International organizations use different
> approaches. The World Bank uses market-based rates to determine the
> weights in its regional and global aggregations of real GDP, whereas
> the IMF and the Organization for Economic Cooperation and Development
> use weights based on PPP rates (although the IMF also publishes a
> global growth aggregate based on market rates in the WEO). Each
> methodology has its advantages and disadvantages.
>
> **Advantages of PPP**
> A main one is that PPP exchange rates are relatively stable over time. By contrast, market rates are more
> volatile, and using them could produce quite large swings in aggregate
> measures of growth even when growth rates in individual countries are
> stable. Another drawback of market-based rates is that they are
> relevant only for internationally traded goods. Nontraded goods and
> services tend to be cheaper in low-income than in high-income
> countries. A haircut in New York is more expensive than in Lima; the
> price of a taxi ride of the same distance is higher in Paris than in
> Tunis; and a ticket to a cricket game costs more in London than in
> Lahore. Indeed, because wages tend to be lower in poorer countries,
> and services are often relatively labor intensive, the price of a
> haircut in Lima is likely to be cheaper than in New York even when the
> cost of making tradable goods, such as machinery, is the same in both
> countries. Any analysis that fails to take into account these
> differences in the prices of nontraded goods across countries will
> underestimate the purchasing power of consumers in emerging market and
> developing countries and, consequently, their overall welfare. For
> this reason, PPP is generally regarded as a better measure of overall
> well-being.
>
> **Drawbacks of PPP**
>
> The biggest one is that PPP is harder to measure than market-based rates. The ICP is a huge statistical undertaking,
> and new price comparisons are available only at infrequent intervals.
> Methodological questions have also been raised about earlier surveys.
> In between survey dates, the PPP rates have to be estimated, which can
> introduce inaccuracies into the measurement. Also, the ICP does not
> cover all countries, which means that data for missing countries have
> to be estimated.

Comment: Thanks. So would you say the GDP at PPP quantifies the value (or _level_) of a country's material well-being (as proxied by consumption)?